# Retrieving Sitecore items Position A in the content tree and to the user in Position B

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Given the following content tree, how could I associate Dealerships with Cars so that I can get a URL like this?

http://website/Dealerships/JimWhite/Ford

I need to be able to have the content viewable and editable under cars, but automatically updated under the dealerships.

I assume there is some kind of link I can do?

- Home

  - Cars

    - Ford
    - Honda
    - Toyota
  - Dealerships

    - JimWhite
    - TomJones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this document on SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc62keywords/reusing_and_sharing_data_sc62_a4001.pdf), especially the chapter about Sharing and Reusing Items and Field Values (Aliases, Proxies, Wildcard items).

Comment: Wildcards were exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into [aliases](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Aliases.aspx) on the SDN.

Comment: Aliases would work, but they would be a lot of work to add since I am talking about a lot of linking back and forth. I landed on using Wildcards and some custom code to make the URLs look as I would like them to.

Comment: Ahh, good to know about the wildcards! I've never used them myself.

Answer (score 0):

My Item Mirror module might do the trick.

http://blog.capaxsolutions.co.uk/2010/06/09/sitecore-item-mirroring-making-an-item-appear-in-more-than-one-place/